# Authorization exception retrieving nexus-maven-repository-index.properties

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

i use vpn and nexus repositories, in ide the same maven is selected as for command line (3.6.3).
via `mvn -s settings-ci.xml -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true clean package`
the project is going, but in IDEA I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KOyu.png

It makes it difficult to debug libraries from the nexus repositories.

In the ide settings "settings-ci.xml" and "Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true" are selected

log:

```
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerIndexerException: java.io.IOException: Authorization exception retrieving nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.updateIndex(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:195)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy225.updateIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:150)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$400(RemoteUtil.java:21)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.lambda$invoke$0(RemoteUtil.java:134)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:31)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:202)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:134)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy225.updateIndex(Unknown Source)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.lambda$updateIndex$1(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:66)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.performCancelable(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.updateIndex(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:63)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateNexusContext(MavenIndex.java:410)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateOrRepair(MavenIndex.java:354)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.updateOrRepair(MavenIndices.java:129)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.doUpdateIndices(MavenIndicesManager.java:355)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager$3.run(MavenIndicesManager.java:319)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:436)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:120)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:496)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:244)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:244)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Authorization exception retrieving nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl$2.run(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:177)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder$2.run(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:355)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder.executeWithSessionScope(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:430)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder.executeWithMavenSession(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:363)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedder.executeWithMavenSession(Maven3ServerEmbedder.java:352)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.updateIndex(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:143)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Authorization exception retrieving nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.retrieve(Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.java:100)
at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.AbstractResourceFetcher.retrieve(AbstractResourceFetcher.java:22)
at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.downloadIndexProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:484)
at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$100(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:65)
at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$IndexAdaptor.setProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:771)
at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:945)
at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:150)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl$2.run(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:174)
... 22 more
  Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Authorization failed for https://... 403 Forbidden
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1180)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1138)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:126)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.retrieve(Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.java:97)
... 29 more
```

Comment: please attach idea.log file, covering the update attempt: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory

Comment: Do you have proxies? It must be configured in Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | 'HTTP Proxy' settings.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov i do not have a proxy, log attached